# Как изменить манифест уже созданному exe файлу

Tags: c#, winforms

Я хочу изменить название своего приложения на выбранный пользователем.
Как я понял - сменить название процесса без перезапуска нельзя, поэтому я хочу изменить манифест уже собранного, моего приложения и вписать туда другое название, после перезапустить приложение.
Есть какие-то идеи по реализации идеи и того что я выше написал?
Использую C# WinForms 4.8. Права доступа процесса не важны.

Comment: Что за название приложения? Имя продукта, отображаемое в свойствах файла? Только перекомпиляцией. Имя окна в панели задач, насколько мне известно, можно менять без проблем. Имя процесса, скорее всего так просто не поменяешь во время работы (перед запуском достаточно exe переименовать), нужно искать winapi функцию для этих целей (если она вообще существует), как самый последний вариант, который может сработать, но который невероятно тяжело реализовать - изменить имя процесса через прямой доступ к ОЗУ системы, но для этого нужен драйвер и нужно знать где это имя хранится. А это отдельная тема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для переименования файла - нужна отдельная утилитка или бат-файл. Утилитка должна выключать программу, переименовывать файл и запускать программу повторно. Это же должно изменить и название процесса в таск менеджере.

Имя продукта отображаемое в свойствах файла... То есть править метадату... Начни с изучения вот этого файла, а конкретнее с секции §II.25 (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#page=303) - это спецификация описывающая CLI. Имея спецификацию на руках можно и разобраться как читать и менять метаданные.

Ну а заголовок окна меняется проще всего - задай свой Window.Title Property

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас, при переименовании сторонних программ мне иногда выдаёт разные ошибки, которые вроде бы влияют на работа-способность.
Я попробую сделать компилятор программы, которая будет переименовывать мой файл и запускать его

Comment: Переименовывай только свою, а чужие не трогай. Часть программ имеют защиту от подобного, например тотал коммандер такую имеет. И тогда он или перестанет работать или же начнет ругаться что на компьютере вирусы. И будет прав ибо вмешательство подобное извне программы является вредоносным.

Comment: Я посмотрел CLI документацию, но ILSpy показывает все метаданные, но не почему-то не показывает часть заголовков(Касающихся того, что мне нужно).
byte code тоже не нашёл совпадений (Я искал имя процесса(переименованного файла))

Comment: так процесс же в превалирующем большинстве случаев называется как и екзешник, на сколько мне не изменяет память. То есть искать это в ИЛ не имеет смысла если он совпадает с именем файла

Comment: ,я думал, а вдруг, когда Windows или что-то ещё меняет название файлу, он меняет ссылку или параметр манифеста файла

Comment: Ну дублировать информацию не имеет смысла. Для чего?